# Show all mail rules on Office 365 web admin interface

Tags: microsoft-office-365

As by subject: is it possible, and how, to show **all** mail rules (especially incoming/forwarding rules) from the Office 365 admin interface locate at https://portal.office.com ?

I know that the Exchange Admin panel shows any transport related rules. However, I can not find where user-defined rules are reported/summarized.

I also know that it is possible to use powershell to retrieve these information, but I feel I am missing something on the web admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

[shodanshok](https://serverfault.com/users/269155/shodanshok),

This functionality is available in the O365 security portal.

[Here's the documentation link.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/alert-policies)

For what it's worth, alerting of new forwarding rules were automatically turned on over the past couple of weeks by Microsoft, via an update.

PS - Fully aware that this is a year old, but others may end up here.